# TCLOO: Private Method And Method As Callback

Tags: tcl

Using Tcloo (self compiled TCL 8.6.7) I implemented a client socket.

I have the folowing issues:

1. I how can make a method private when declare using only oo::create class
2. How can I register the method of the class as the event callback for the 
   socket.
   I have tried the following:

   chan event $sock readable [list readSocket $sock]
   Error: invalid command name "readSocket"...

   chan event $sock readable [list [self] readSocket $sock]
   Error: invalid command name "self"...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods with names that start with a lower-case letter are public, others are private. You can also use `export` and `unexport`.

```
oo::class create C {
    method foo args {}  ;# public

    method Bar args {}  ;# private

    method Baz args {}  ;# private
    export Baz          ;# now it's public

    method quux args {} ;# public
    unexport quux       ;# now it's private
}
```

As usual in Tcl you can use a variety of methods to define a callback. You need to know which namespace the object uses and qualify the `my` method to that namespace.

From within an object, the namespace can be introspected using `self namespace` or `namespace which my`, but the easiest way is to use `namespace code`:

```
namespace code {my readSocket $sock}
namespace code [list my readSocket $sock]
```

The difference between these is that in the upper line, `$sock` gets variable substituted when the callback is called, and in the second line, it gets substituted when the callback is defined. The result of this invocation is a namespace-independent command prefix that can be executed by any evaluating command. Note that `sock` must be visible in the context: a regular namespace variable isn't visible unless `variable` has been called on it; a TclOO class level variable is visible inside all methods.

From outside the object, the object's namespace can be identified using `info object namespace`:

```
list [info object namespace $obj]::my readSocket $sock
```

(Evaluates `sock` in caller namespace at the time the callback is defined.)

Documentation:
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[my](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/my.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm),
[oo::class](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/class.htm),
[oo::define](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have also tracked down the cause of the errors, they occured because I used "namespace path {::tcl::mathop}" to access the mathop operator commands. I have imported the namespace and the errors are gone. Thanks, problem solved

Comment: I've been wondering whether I ought to write a helper command to create callbacks, but it would be just doing much as the answer options listed above describe.